# Is it possible to send msg.value amounts from an EOA?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm creating a txn that will send ERC-20 tokens to a bridge contract, which also requires some msg.value in ether to be sent. Is the only way to send this tx to require the Gnosis Safe to have that ETH balance? I was wondering if there is a way to configure the msg.value of the outer txn executed by the multisig owner, so that the required msg.value would be taken from the owner wallet instead of funding the safe in prior.

Comment: This is not possible. You need to send ETH to the Safe wallet.